# How to manage Login and Logout session in android - with Server Json object request

Tags: android, json, session, authentication, logout

Friends,

I have a problem on how to manage login and logout session in online android mobile application with user login functionality.

I have read many article on shared preference for this type of application. but is it also useful for online application?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use SharedPreferences for this kind of stuff, I do that all the time. For example you can have a SharedPreferences object that contains for example data giving the status (connected or not) and other information about the connected user.

Answer (score 0):

I understood, that you would like to let user login in your online service, right? If this is correct you should use Accounts. 
Two links that may help you. (I'm not allowed to post more, but look at the Documentation for Accounts and the AccountManager)

[The Authorization](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html)

[Tutorial](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) (Please check the GitHub repository as well to understand the tutorial)